# gvim copy/paste shortcuts like in terminal : ctrl+shift+v / c

Tags: key-bindings, gvim, os-clipboard

In terminal I use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

to copy & paste.

I would like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> in gVim to have standard Vim behaviour.

How to configure gVim, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> become shortcuts for default clipboard ( i.e. `"+gP` `"+y`), while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> stay unaffected ?

Answer (score 1):

### Note:

It was brought to my attention by [Matt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/22797/matt) that Vim keybindings involving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are case insensitive, making it impossible to have a keybind <kbd>C-S-c</kbd> or <kbd>C-S-v</kbd> independently of <kbd>C-c</kbd> and <kbd>C-v</kbd> - along with further testing revealing that any <kbd>C-c</kbd> based binding gets caught by the terminal as <kbd>C-c</kbd> -  meaning that unless you wish to override the default uses - or wish to use it at all in the cace of <kbd>C-S-c</kbd> -  you would have to instead use <kbd>M-S-c</kbd> and <kbd>M-S-v</kbd>/<kbd>C-M-v</kbd> or some other alternative.

---

GVim uses vim's default .vimrc file (~/.vimrc) so you need to add mappings there. In this case, depending on which mode(s) you want the mapping to be available in, you would add one or more of the following (excluding comments) to your .vimrc:

Copy:

```
nnoremap <M-S-c> "+y  " Normal (must follow with an operator)
xnoremap <M-S-c> "+y  " Visual
```

Paste:

```
nnoremap <M-S-v> "+p  " Normal
noremap! <M-S-v> <C-r>+  " Insert and Command line
inoremap <M-S-v> <C-r>+  " Insert
```

If you want these mappings to only occur in gVim and not in normal vim, then add the following:

```
if has("gui_running")  " Check if running in a GUI (gVim)
  [Insert mappings here]
endif
```

Edit: Thanks to [Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/343/rich) in the comments for mentioning, instead of checking if a GUI is running you can put the mappings in the .gvimrc file (~/.gvimrc), a .vimrc used specifically by gVim.

Comment: you may want to check up on mswin.vim, see `:h mswin.vim`

Comment: You could also put the settings in `.gvimrc` instead of checking `gui_running`.

Comment: Please, before suggesting some piece of code go check it yourself first and fix the bugs: comments are not allowed after maps; normal map switches into operator-pending mode making it pretty much unusable; select map does not work at all; "shifted key" does not work on many platforms including Windows, etc.etc.

Comment: Apologies, the comments were more meant to indicate which mode each one works in than to be actually included and with normal mode a operator would be required to indicate what to copy (and I will admit I've never encountered select mode outside of seeing it in the docs next to visual mode), but I did forget that control commands are for the most part case insensitive and will edit the answer to explain that.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, I have `<C-c>` set up to yank to `"+` in terminal vim (for visual selection), which works fine, my terminal doesn't catch it (but outside vim it still works as expected, so it's definitely vim stealing it from the terminal).